# How to temporarily exclude property from getting saved to RavenDb?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb

I need to store some data from user input to RavenDb. But while the user is typing some property might have changed which I don't want to get overwritten. So I want to temporarily exclude this property from getting saved. Is that possible? I know the solution with "JsonIgnore", but then the property would be ignored permanently.

Comment: Why would you save the data while user is still editing? Just use other TempObject or whatever it is to create the final object to save in db when you are ready

Answer (score 3):

I think that a better approach would be to reverse this question.
Instead of trying to save the whole object, and ignore changes to a particular property, why not just set the properties that you want to set?

Here are the relevant docs:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document#change-values-of-two-fields

And this is how you set just two properties, and leave the rest as is:

```
session.Advanced.Patch<Employee, string>("employees/1", x => x.FirstName, "Robert");
session.Advanced.Patch<Employee, string>("employees/1", x => x.LastName, "Carter");

session.SaveChanges();
```